# Mule4: How to define oneway and twoway pattern in IBM MQ connector

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component, mule4

How to select oneway or two way in Mule IBM connector Config?

Is there a way we can mention in the config it is `oneway` or 'twoway (requestReply)' pattern externally. In this new version looks like it is always a 2 way (requestReply). I couldn't see any option to choose as in old connector. I wanted oneway here as i'm not expecting reply for the message.

```
        <flow name="NotificationFlow" doc:id="a275ef91-8608-49a5-adcc-624c2dc6aacd" >
        <ibm-mq:listener doc:name="On New Message" doc:id="5de4cf1b-bd66-4519-b170-69f2159bd8b4" config-ref="IBM_MQ_Config" destination="testQ" ackMode="AUTO"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="9c4c241b-d564-44ff-a2a3-6433e48ddf0a" />
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="46c10c0c-3f0a-4184-a722-7caab39ca97d" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
var result = []
output application/java
---
if(sizeOf(result) <= 0) fail('Data was empty') else result]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
```

Using Mule version: 4.2.2

Comment: Are you receiving any reply with the default configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Mule IBM MQ connector listener operation, responses are automatic only [when the message includes a REPLY_TO header](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/ibm/ibm-mq-listener#replying-to-incoming-messages). Since the [IBM MQ version 1.6.0](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/connector-ibm-mq#1-6-0) it is possible to dissable the automatic REPLY_TO with the `ignoreReplyTo` attribute.

Example:

So I would not expect any reply by default unless the sender is requesting it using the REPLY_TO header.

Comment: Thanks for the details Response. I'm using IBM v1.5.6 hence no `ignoreReplyTo`. In my response there is no "REPLY_TO" been set so i assume there is "no reply" settings externally i need to set. Question arises bcz in old connector, If it is one way `icon` changes to `oneDirection`. In the new connector we are not visually able to see as one way. No worries got you. Thank you :)